# Inserting latitude and longitude into MySQL database

Tags: php

Have been trying for days on this code to insert latitude and longitude generated from google api. Heere is my code and error:

```
//Use the above code before the file_get_content. means, use the following code
$address1 = str_replace(" ", "+", $address1);
$json = file_get_contents("http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=$address1&sensor=false&region=GTH");
$json = json_decode($json);

$lat = $json->{'results'}[0]->{'geometry'}->{'location'}->{'lat'};
$long = $json->{'results'}[1]->{'geometry'}->{'location'}->{'lng'};

//DATABASE INSERTION
include'include/convert.php';
     $sqlquery3="insert
     into
     corp
     (lat,lon) "."VALUES
     ('$lat','$long')";
```

> Error Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\Program Files\Apache Software
>   Foundation\Apache2.2\htdocs\gg\companyregistration.php on line 207
>
> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\Program
>   Files\Apache Software
>   Foundation\Apache2.2\htdocs\gg\companyregistration.php on line 207
>
> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\Program
>   Files\Apache Software
>   Foundation\Apache2.2\htdocs\gg\companyregistration.php on line 207
>
> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\Program
>   Files\Apache Software
>   Foundation\Apache2.2\htdocs\gg\companyregistration.php on line 207

Comment: And which of these PHP lines is line number 207?

Comment: the error is caused by the $long = ....... line, try to do a var_dump of $json to see what it contains.

Comment: Did you try `print_r($json)` ? As the error say, there is no index 1. So your results contains something else...

Answer (score 2):

Why are you mixing **index 0** and **index 1** ?

Google API is returning an array of addresses. If your request returns 1 possible answer,  results array  will contain only 1 entry.

To get the latitude & longitude of the first address :

```
$lat = $json->{'results'}[0]->{'geometry'}->{'location'}->{'lat'};
$long = $json->{'results'}[0]->{'geometry'}->{'location'}->{'lng'};
```

By doing :

```
$lat = $json->{'results'}[0]->{'geometry'}->{'location'}->{'lat'};
$long = $json->{'results'}[1]->{'geometry'}->{'location'}->{'lng'};
```

You are using the latitude of the 1st result and the longitude of the 2nd result (in your case there is no second result).

Comment: Dont understand the answer given. Still getting the error'  Trying to get property of non-objec

Comment: Do a `print_r($json)`, you'll understand. You are not used the right index.

Comment: i got this after print_r($json)